# Kafka : Consumer is taking ~ 2 sec to fetch next batch

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have set kafka config. as below for consumer

```
consumer:
  bootstrap-servers: ${VAR1}
  group-id: ${VAR2}
  auto-offset-reset: earliest
  key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  properties:
    max:
      poll:
        records: 20
        interval.ms: 300000
listener:
  ack-mode: manual
```

I observed after consuming one batch successfully kafka consumer is taking time to fetch next batch,
It is taking approximately 1.5 ~ 2sec

Can anyone help to understand how to reduce this kafka batch interval of ~2sec and configure to get the next batch immediately

Comment: How long does it take you to process those 20 records you've requested?